# How to make specific query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from  Orders;
+------+------+------+------------+------------+
| ONO  | CNO  | ENO  | RECEIVED   | SHIPPED    |
+------+------+------+------------+------------+
| 1020 | 1111 | 1000 | 1994-12-10 | 1994-12-12 |
| 1021 | 1111 | 1000 | 1995-01-12 | 1995-01-15 |
| 1022 | 2222 | 1001 | 1995-02-13 | 1995-02-20 |
| 1023 | 3333 | 1000 | 2003-02-15 | NULL       |
| 1024 | 4444 | 1000 | 2003-02-15 | 2003-02-16 |
| 1025 | 5555 | 1000 | 2003-02-15 | 2003-02-16 |
+------+------+------+------------+------------+

mysql> select * from Employees;
+------+--------+-------+------------+
| ENO  | ENAME  | ZIP   | HDATE      |
+------+--------+-------+------------+
| 1000 | Jones  | 67226 | 1995-12-12 |
| 1001 | Smith  | 60606 | 1992-01-01 |
| 1002 | Brown  | 50302 | 1994-09-01 |
| 1003 | Green  | 28411 | 2002-09-01 |
| 1004 | Purple | 28411 | 2003-01-01 |
+------+--------+-------+------------+

mysql> select * from Customers;
+------+---------+------------------+-------+--------------+
| CNO  | CNAME   | STREET           | ZIP   | PHONE        |
+------+---------+------------------+-------+--------------+
| 1111 | Charles | 123 Main St.     | 67226 | 316-636-5555 |
| 2222 | Bertram | 237 Ash Avenue   | 67226 | 316-689-5555 |
| 3333 | Barbara | 111 Inwood St.   | 60606 | 316-111-1234 |
| 4444 | Will    | 111 Kenwood St.  | 54444 | 416-111-1234 |
| 5555 | Bill    | 211 Marlwood St. | 28408 | 416-111-1235 |
| 6666 | Keely   | 211 Pinewood St. | 28411 | 416-111-1235 |
| 7777 | Maera   | 211 Marlwood St. | 28408 | 416-111-1235 |
+------+---------+------------------+-------+--------------+
```

I need to: Get `cname` and `ename` pairs such that the customer with name
`cname` has placed an order through employee with name `ename`.

I'm sure this seems easy to most but I have not been able to figure
this out. I have tried this:

```
select distinct Customers.CNAME, Employees.ENAME
from   Customers, Employees
where  Customers.CNO in (
    select Customers.CNO
    from   Customers, Orders
    where  Customers.CNO = Orders.CNO
) and
where  Employees.ENO in (
    select Employees.ENO
    from   Orders, Employees
    where  Employees.ENO = Orders.ENO
);
```

in multiple versions, but I can't seem to get it to work. This is my first time working in SQL so it is very new to me. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't use IN, use JOIN and it will be simple.

Comment: But how do I do it with 3 tables? It's simple in my mind to do a join with two tables, but it's confusing with 3. I've tried nesting them, but I just get errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select customers.CNAME, employees.ENAME from customers 
inner join orders on customers.CNO = orders.CNO
inner join employees on orders.ENO = employees.ENO;
```

Using join statements makes it easier to read the SQL you are trying to do. This joins orders table to customers on the CNO value and orders table with employees on the ENO value. It then selects two columns for display.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm ashamed to say how much time I spent on this problem so this was very helpful. The join does make readability a lot better and makes me understand the process more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  a select distinc with a pair of join  ( left join if could be that the on condition don't match or inner join if ever match )

```
select distinct c.cname, e.ename
from Customers as c
left join Orders as o as o on o.cno = c.cno
left join Employees on e.eno =  o.eno

select distinct c.cname, e.ename
from Customers as c
inner join Orders as o as o on o.cno = c.cno
inner join Employees on e.eno =  o.eno
```

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen   yes  ... correct .. thanks  .. answer  updated

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CNAME,Employees.ENAME FROM Customers 
 JOIN Orders ON Customers.CNO=Orders.CNO 
 JOIN Employees ON Employees.ENO=Orders.ENO;
```

or

```
 SELECT DISTINCT Customers.CNAME,Employees.ENAME from Customers 
 JOIN Orders USING (CNO) 
 JOIN Employees USING(ENO);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cname, e.ename
  FROM orders o
  JOIN employees e USING (eno)
  JOIN clients c USING (cno);
```